# MigLayout limits scrolling of a JList on a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist, miglayout

I have a GUI that consists of multiple JList components on a panel, which is on a JScrollPane. The scroll pane makes it possible to scroll all of the lists at once. However, when I use MigLayout on the panel containing the lists I am unable to scroll past the first 1819 list elements. The limitation appears to be related to the height of the list, not the number of elements. If I use larger element sizes I can scroll less elements. I'm currently using MigLayout 4.2.

Here is a simplified example that exhibits this behavior.

```
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public final class MigLayoutListTest {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final String[] listData = new String[5000];
                for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
                    listData[i] = "Index " + i;
                }

                final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());
                panel.add(new JList(listData));

                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setContentPane(new JScrollPane(panel));

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

If I eliminate the JPanel and put the JList directly on the JScrollPane then scrolling works correctly, but I cannot use this workaround since I need multiple lists on the same JScrollPane. If I use any layout other than MigLayout for the JPanel then scrolling works correctly.

Is this a bug or limitation of MigLayout? Is there some configuration option that needs to be applied to MigLayout in order to get it working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your approach is kludgy. Rather, use JLists in their own JScrollPane and synch up the scrolling:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ScrollingDemo implements Runnable
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ScrollingDemo());
  }

  public void run()
  {
    JScrollPane sp1 = new JScrollPane(getJList(1));
    sp1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    JScrollPane sp2 = new JScrollPane(getJList(3));
    sp2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    JScrollBar sBar1 = sp1.getVerticalScrollBar();
    JScrollBar sBar2 = sp2.getVerticalScrollBar();

    // synchronize:
    sBar2.setModel(sBar1.getModel());

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
    p.add(sp1);
    p.add(sp2);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Synch Scrolling");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public JList getJList(int factor)   
  {
    Vector<String> items = new Vector<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
      items.add(Integer.toString((i+1)*factor));
    }
    JList list = new JList(items);
    list.setPrototypeCellValue("XXXXXXXXXX");
    list.setVisibleRowCount(10);
    return list;
  }
}
```

If only want to see 1 vertical scrollbar, just set the scrollbar policy to `JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER` on the ones you want to hide.

**NOTE:** This assumes that each JList has the same number of elements. If you had multiple lists of varying length, you'd probably (instead) need to add an `AdjustmentListener` to the vertical scrollbars.

**EDIT:** Example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ScrollingDemo2 implements Runnable
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ScrollingDemo2());
  }

  public void run()
  {
    JScrollPane sp1 = new JScrollPane(getJList(100));
    sp1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    JScrollPane sp2 = new JScrollPane(getJList(200));
    sp2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    // synchronize:
    sp2.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(new Synchronizer(sp1, sp2));

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
    p.add(sp1);
    p.add(sp2);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Synch Scrolling 2");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public JList getJList(int count)   
  {
    Vector<String> items = new Vector<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      items.add(Integer.toString(i+1));
    }

    JList list = new JList(items);
    list.setPrototypeCellValue("XXXXXXXXXX");
    list.setVisibleRowCount(10);
    return list;
  }

  class Synchronizer implements AdjustmentListener
  {
    JScrollPane sp1, sp2;

    public Synchronizer(JScrollPane sp1, JScrollPane sp2)
    {
      this.sp1 = sp1;
      this.sp2 = sp2;
    }

    public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e)
    {
      if (! e.getValueIsAdjusting())
      {
        return;
      }

      JScrollBar vert1 = sp1.getVerticalScrollBar();
      JScrollBar vert2 = sp2.getVerticalScrollBar();

      int range1 = vert1.getMaximum() - vert1.getMinimum() -
                   vert1.getModel().getExtent();

      int range2 = vert2.getMaximum() - vert2.getMinimum() -
                   vert2.getModel().getExtent();

      float percent2 = (float) (vert2.getValue()) / range2;
      int newVal1 = (int) (percent2 * range1);

      vert1.setValue(newVal1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a neat trick and it works well for this example, unfortunately the lists I'm working with have different numbers of elements and I have to limit the GUI to one scrollbar. I think this is a bug in MigLayout 4.2 and have tested it out on multiple machines with the same results.